# Saving the ListView state in android

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView in my main page(**MainActivity.java**) and I want to keep the ListView's position(if it was scrolled up I want to show the exact ListView position) when user comes back to main page.

Since the MainActivity goes to onPause() -> onStop() method when the user clicked a list item,
I am saving the state of ListView inside onPause(). For get the return **Parcelable** value I use a global variable called **state**.

```
state = list.onSaveInstanceState(); //line 1
```

When the user comes back to the MainActivity() it goes through the onStart(), so I get the saved states inside onStart().

```
if (state != null) {
        //set adapter to listview
        list.setAdapter(myAdapter);
        //Restore previous state
        list.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
}
```

The problem is **line 1** doesn't return any state.(It gives a null value).
How to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: To achieve what you want you will need to get the current position of the scrollbar (or the "y") and save it somewhere, then when returning set the scrollbar to previously saved position.

Comment: @Andy : I get the y value inside onItemClick  y =list.getScrollY(); and set the y value inside onStart() ->list.setScrollY(y); But still not getting it??

Answer (score 1):

I use this:

```
Parcelable state = listView.onSaveInstanceState();
```

before adding the adapter and this:

```
listView.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
```

exactly after setting the adapter and I have the result you are looking for.
Just try it out

Comment: you mean inside onCreate() ??

Comment: where do you set your adapter? If you are doing everything in onCreate() then I suppose yes

Comment: Parcelable state = listView.onSaveInstanceState(); should be called in the onItemClick, isn't it? before leaving the screen.

Comment: no I don't have it in the onItemClick. just before it

Answer (score 0):

To get current position of listview you have to implement OnScrollListener and set listener with your listview like,

```
listView.setOnScrollListener(this);
```

then, in onScroll method you can do your stuff

```
@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView absListView, int firstVisibleItem, int totalVisibleItem, int totalItemInList) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // here you can save listview's scroll state
            // you can see methods parameters
}
```

and when you get back to your main activity you can use setSelection method of listview like,

```
listView.setSelection(firstVisibleItem);
```

i hope this is all you want.

Comment: I didn't test your method. But I figured out that my MainActivity.java class goes to onSaveInstanceState() -> onDestroy() when coming back to main page. So can I use your method?? I tried to get the saved state in a bundle, still it is not working.

Comment: I can't understand why the activity is destroying instead of going to onStart() method? Any idea??

Comment: yes, you can still use this method to save state. create global static variable in any intermediate class and save your state in this variable. Try to put some code you have used to go to another activity and get back to MainActivity to understand destroying problem.